# Why is sunlight not affecting the vampire here?

Tags: plot-explanation, priest

In [Priest (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priest_(2011_film)), why is the sunlight not affecting the vampire in this scene?

[image]

Comment: *Does* sunlight affect vampires in this setting?  In some settings they burst into flame immediately, in others they just get uncomfortable in the light.  (In *some settings* they just sparkle...)

Comment: Why do you assume it kills them? That whole 'sunlight is deadly for vampires' idea was first used in the movies, in "Nosferatu"(1922). It is never said in Bram Stoker's "Count Dracula" that sunlight is bad for them, and in that novel, Dracula walks around in the daytime.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that character is Karl Urban's 'Black Hat' character:

[image]

From [your link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priest_(2011_film)):

> Black Hat is revealed as one of the Priests who was defeated in the final attack on Sola Mira and a close friend of Priest. After being captured, the vampire Queen gave him her blood, **turning him into the first Vampire-Human hybrid who can survive the sun**.

Comment: I haven't seen the film but are we sure that the "vampire" isn't the woman?

Comment: @Catija - the vampire isn't the woman. She is someone (a friends daughter i think) that the eponymous Priest has to save